# What is callbackURL in consumer key creation?

Tags: salesforce, mule

I want to consume API in mule esb from salesforce, using OAuth 2.0 so to get consumer key i'm configuring in salesforce API. I struct at callBack URL.

What does it mean? what should be the callback URL ?

Answer (score 1):

Callback URL is the url that will being called on successful completion of the request validation in Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Abani answered it well, just to explain more: Callback URL are those which you will mention while registering an oAuth App and will be redirected along with token, there you can write your business logic to get token and use it to consume data.

There is javascript version of oAuth implementation of Salesforce API, and  can be used to understand the authentication flow: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ULWBdjJx1Ss

The video describes STEP BY STEP process required to obtain token and use it to get data.

Answer (score 0):

Call back URL is the URL called when the request is completed.That means after the requested is completed where the control should go we will say in call back url.After the completion of the request, it will redirect to that url. In sales force OAuth authentication we will use the callback URL